# Join on foreign key of table with the max primary key of that table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max, inner-join

I have a workers table and an events table.

`Workers.ID = Events.WorkerID`. I need to join these tables in a query but i need to do so on the `MAX(ID)` of the events table. I can't figure out how to do this.

My base attempt:

```
SELECT ID, Fname, SName
FROM workers w inner join `events`on w.ID = Events.workerID.
```

Right now this gives me multiple instances of where the workerid exists in the events table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `workers` (
  `ID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `FName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Sname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Pass` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Birthday` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `companyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isAvailable` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
`ID` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `WorkerID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `startLatitude` double NOT NULL,
  `startLongitude` double NOT NULL,
  `startDateTime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `startLoc` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `isOvertime` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1013 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: First of all, remove one of the `FROM WORKERS` from your query.

Comment: Please show the table structure of both tables; I assume you don't want to reduce the `Events` table to the single entry with the max `ID` but to get each event for each worker with the single ID for this special worker present?

Comment: @Smutje Yes I do want to reduce the Events table to a single entry with the max ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT w.*, e.*
FROM workers w
LEFT JOIN events e
    ON w.id = e.workerID 
        AND e.id = (
            SELECT MAX(e2.id) 
            FROM events e2 
            WHERE e2.workerID = w.id
        )
```

Hope this help ;)

Comment: i really need to  get the hang of joining on the same table twice and using table aliases, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Select the highest event ID grouped by worker IDs...

```
select max(e.ID)
from events e
group by e.WorkerID
```

...and join the resulting event IDs with the worker table

```
select *
from (
  select e.WorkerID, max(e.ID)
  from events e
  group by e.WorkerID
) as max_e
inner join workers w on max_e.WorkerID = w.ID
```